# Calling PRIVATE package procedure from public

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a package with both public and private procedures as follows. But I am unable to compile it:

```
create or replace package tst_pkg
as
    procedure local_pkg ( p_id integer );
end tst_pkg;
/
create or replace package body tst_pkg
as

    procedure local_pkg ( p_id integer )
    is
    begin
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'P_ID: ' || p_id );
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'Now calling PRIV_PROC' );
            tst_pkg.priv_proc ( 999 );
    end;

    procedure priv_proc ( p_id integer )
    is
    begin
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'In PRIV_PROC P_ID: ' || p_id );
    end;

    end tst_pkg;
    /
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put your private procedures first in the package.
A packaged procedure or function can only see ones that are either public or declare ahead of them in the package body.

```
create or replace package body tst_pkg
as

    procedure priv_proc ( p_id integer )
    is
    begin
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'In PRIV_PROC P_ID: ' || p_id );
    end;

    procedure local_pkg ( p_id integer )
    is
    begin
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'P_ID: ' || p_id );
            dbms_output.put_line ( 'Now calling PRIV_PROC' );
            tst_pkg.priv_proc ( 999 );
    end;

    end tst_pkg;
    /
```

Very occasionally you might have code where procedure BLUE calls procedure RED and procedure RED calls procedure BLUE and you have to get complicated with [forward declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99896)

```
create or package body pkg_col is
  --
  procedure blue (p_in in number);
  procedure red (p_in in number;
  --
  procedure blue (p_in in number) is
  begin
    red (1);
  end blue;
  procedure red (p_in in number) is
  begin
    if p_in > 1 then
      blue (2);
    end if;
  end red;
end pkg_col;
```